# Create a new image file from a drawable

Tags: android

I have a problem.
I am selecting an image from the gallery in android and showing it in an imageview.
What I want to do is create another file with another name and copy this image to this file inside a directory in my applications resources.
Can anyone help me please.

Answer (score 2):

You can launch the gallery picker intent with the following:

```
public void imageFromGallery() {
Intent getImageFromGalleryIntent = 
  new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(getImageFromGalleryIntent, SELECT_IMAGE);
}
```

Then when it returns, get the path of the selected image with the following portion of code:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    switch(requestCode) {
    case SELECT_IMAGE:
        mSelectedImagePath = getPath(data.getData());
        break;
  }
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
startManagingCursor(cursor);
int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
cursor.moveToFirst();
return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Now that you have the pathname in a string you can copy it to another location.

```
try {
File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
if (sd.canWrite()) {
    String sourceImagePath= "/path/to/source/file.jpg";
    String destinationImagePath= "/path/to/destination/file.jpg";
    File source= new File(data, souceImagePath);
    File destination= new File(sd, destinationImagePath);
    if (source.exists()) {
        FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(source).getChannel();
        FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(destination).getChannel();
        dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
        src.close();
        dst.close();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

This will do your job i think..

Also go through this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal)